# Error cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript

That's what my JavaScript look like

JS:

```
const secondHand = document.querySelector(".sechand");
secondHand.style.width = "10px";
```

This is when run on Chrome mobile browser.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should learn how to debug JavaScript code in Chrome. Review [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the error is that your selector turned up null, then you haven't correctly selected the element.

Either you don't have an element that has the class "sechand"... or, more likely, you're running the JS before the DOM is ready. Try running your JS on an 'onload' event, or place it at the bottom of your page.